# Choosing Vuex modules per page in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

In a Nuxt app I have the following store modules

```
// store/a.js
export default {
  state: {
    a: 0
  }
}
// store/b.js
export default {
  state: {
    b: 0
  }
}
```

and three pages. I want the first page to use only module a, the second to only use module b and the third to not use a Vuex store at all. Is there a simple way to do it? I know I could move my modules outside of the store directory and then use store.registerModule in the created hook of each page component, but that doesn't look really clean to me.

Comment: i think when u need to use store you need to import in the component so you choose which one to import or not import it if not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Every `.js` file inside the store directory is transformed as a [namespaced module](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/directory-structure/store/#modules).

so, your when you create `a.js` and `b.js` in store, you will have to access them using namespace like this.

```js
store.dispatch('a/actionname', value);

store.dispatch('b/mutationname', value);
```

And when using nuxt there is no need for importing `a.js` or `b.js`. You can just use it like this out of the box.

```js
this.$store.commit('a/save', cart);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that doesn't answer my question. I already know how Nuxt does it without extra configuration, my question is about how to do it WITH extra configuration to change that default behavior

Comment: I see, so your requirement is to stop using namespace? Otherwise it all boils down to which namespace you are using. If you don't want component B to use module `b.js` then you don't use `commit('b/something')`.